# Identify last (or first) non-blank cell in range

Tags: numbers, iwork

Is there a way to identify the last (or first) non-blank cell in a range?  Consider a sheet that may have multiple rows with blank cells in a certain column.  In a cell, I'd like to use the value of the closest non-blank cell in the same column.

A cell in a row of column A might contain the formula fragment `OFFSET ( $A$2, 0, 0, ROW() -1,  1 )` to reference the range of cells in the same column from row 2 to the row above the current row.  Is there a way to select the last non-blank value in that range?

Comment: Which spreadsheet app are you using? Version?

Comment: Apple iWorks Numbers '09